# RichTextBlock HasOverflow is incorrect

Tags: c#, xaml, printing, uwp, richtextblock

I am setting up printing functionality in my app. To do this, I have two pages: `PrintPage` and `OverflowPage`. Both inherit from my custom abstract `Page`, `PrintablePage`. Here are the XAML layouts for them:

`PrintPage.xaml`

```
<RelativePanel>

    <RelativePanel x:Name="Header"
                   BorderBrush="Gray"
                   BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                   Margin="48 48 48 12"
                   Padding="0 0 0 6"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True">

        <TextBlock x:Name="RouteTextBlock"
                   Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="{x:Bind Route, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="StaffTextBlock"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                   Margin="0 6 0 0"
                   RelativePanel.Below="RouteTextBlock"
                   Text="{x:Bind Staff, Mode=OneWay}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="Legend"
                   FontSize="14"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                   Margin="0 12 0 24"
                   RelativePanel.Below="StaffTextBlock">

            <Run FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Kimble.ttf#Kimble-UWP"
                 FontSize="16"
                 Text="&#xf106;" /> = Parent must be present for pickup

        </TextBlock>

        <Grid x:Name="DataHeader"
              RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.Below="Legend">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="NameHeader"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="Name" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="AddressHeader"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="Address" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="AgeHeader"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Grid.Column="4"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Right"
                       Text="Age" />
        </Grid>

    </RelativePanel>

    <RichTextBlock x:Name="MainContentTextBlock"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   RelativePanel.Above="InstructionsTextBlock"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="Header" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="InstructionsTextBlock"
               Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
               Margin="0 0 0 24"
               RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
               Text="Please fill out this form and return it at the end of the night" />

</RelativePanel>
```

`OverflowPage.xaml`

```
<RelativePanel Margin="0 0 0 12">

    <Grid x:Name="Header"
          BorderBrush="Gray"
          BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
          Margin="48 48 48 12"
          Padding="0 0 0 6"
          RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
          RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
          RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="NameHeader"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="Name" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AddressHeader"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Grid.Column="3"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="Address" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AgeHeader"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Grid.Column="4"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Right"
                   Text="Age" />
    </Grid>

    <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="OverflowBlock"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                           RelativePanel.Below="Header" />

</RelativePanel>
```

In the constructor for `PrintPage` I render a list of items:

```
var pageWidthBinding = new Binding
{
    FallbackValue = 0,
    TargetNullValue = 0,
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("PageWidth"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
};

foreach (var child in Children)
{
    var uiContainer = new InlineUIContainer();
    var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
    {
        Content = child,
        ContentTemplate = ChildItemTemplate
    };
    contentPresenter.SetBinding(WidthProperty, pageWidthBinding);
    uiContainer.Child = contentPresenter;
    var paragraph = new Paragraph { LineHeight = 18, Margin = new Thickness(0) };
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(uiContainer);
    MainContentTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
}
```

`PageWidth` is a `DependencyProperty` which I set in the page's `SizeChanged` event handler.

The `ChildItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ChildItemTemplate"
              x:DataType="models:Child">
    <Grid Height="18"
          Margin="48 12">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <FontIcon x:Name="ParentPresentIcon"
                  x:Load="{x:Bind ParentMustBePresent}"
                  FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Kimble.ttf#Kimble-UWP"
                  FontSize="16"
                  Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                  Glyph="&#xf106;"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Border x:Name="HereCheckBox"
                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Height="18"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="18" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="{x:Bind FullName}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                   Text="{x:Bind Address}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Right"
                   Text="{x:Bind Age}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have two helper methods on `PrintPage` and `OverflowPage` which the print service calls:

```
public override PrintablePage GetOverflowContent() =>
    new OverflowPage(MainContentTextBlock);
```

and

```
public override bool HasOverflow() => 
    MainContentTextBlock.HasOverflowContent;
```

The constructor for `OverflowPage` then sets the parameter's (a `RichTextBlock`) `OverflowContentTarget` property to `OverflowPage`'s `OverflowBlock`.

This all works fine. However, there's one bug I seem to have hit. The system doesn't appear to properly calculate the `HasOverflowContent` property. As you can see in this image, there is clearly overflow content (it's being clipped), yet `HasOverflowContent` is always false.

[image: Paper]
(Note that there is content being rendered correctly on the rest of the page, but I've erased it for privacy reasons.)

This is happening on `OverflowPage`, but I think it's safe to assume the same problem would also be present on `PrintPage`.

Am I missing something that's affecting my layout, or is this a bug in the system?

Apologies for the wall of text, but with what appears to be a layout issue I think I'd better post any code that could possibly affect it.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803012/4184842) to see if it helps... `HasOverflowContent` is a little tricky.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Ok, let me just make sure I'm understanding what you did there correctly. Are you suggesting that (in my case) my `HasOverflow` should be async and perform your `await <RTB>.FinishLayoutAsync()` before returning a value?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Alright, so I made my `HasOverflow` asynchronous, ran the `FinishLayoutAsync` method and, with a few additional changes to my print service to make it work asynchronously, I'm now getting my overflow content correctly. Thanks! If you add your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasOverflowContent` isn't necessarily available synchronously; you need to wait for it to become available. But simply listening to the `LayoutUpdated` event or `awaiting` for the next UI tick aren't enough - you need to do both. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803012/4184842) from a related question has code to do it.